# multiple options select at a time radio buttons

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I have `<FORM>` wherein I have radio buttons areated for an item.
Code for radio buttons is as below:

```
<tr>
    <td width="10%" align="right" name="Items"><p>Items</p></td>
    <td width="90%">
    <input type="radio" name="None" value="--">None
    <input type="radio" name="Item1" value="Item1">Item1
    <input type="radio" name="Item2" value="Item2">Item2
    <input type="radio" name="Item3" value="Item3">Item3
    <input type="radio" name="Item4" value="Item4">Item4
    </tr>
```

Problem: I want to make it select multiple options of radio button items to get selected and submit at a single time and but able to achieve it.

Comment: Why not use checkboxes instead? http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlcheckboxes.php

Comment: Hi Shobit,thanks for your response! checkboxes is fine, but throughout my whole website i have followed trend of these radio boxes, so want to go ahead in same manner

Comment: Different form element for a different purpose. You don't have to follow a "trend" when it comes to using one or the other. Radio buttons are designed to do what you want.

Comment: I think it's a little counter-intuitive to use radio buttons for multiple selection. Users may not realize it's multiple choice. Plus, it will be difficult to "uncheck" a radio button if the user mistakenly chooses two options.

Comment: You have only formulated a problem description but not a question. What is your concrete programming question?

Answer (score 1):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/3CxLD/2/)

Since you insist using radios, I would go with a jQuery library to get your values. You can add a `class` to your radios and it will allow you to select that `class` and iterate through it. It's counter-intuitive and dirty, but it will work. This markup:

```
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="None" value="--" />None
<br />
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="Item1" value="Item1" />Item1
<br />
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="Item2" value="Item2" />Item2
<br />
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="Item3" value="Item3" />Item3
<br />
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="Item4" value="Item4" />Item4
<br />
```

Goes with this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        // Radios
        $(".rad:checked").each(function() {
            console.log("Radio: " + $(this).val());
        });
    });
})
```

In the fiddle, I added checkboxes too, just to show you how much more easy it is i.e. the following markup (which reads easier and is not as ambiguous):

```
<input name="choices" type="checkbox" value="something1" />Option 1
<br />
<input name="choices" type="checkbox" value="something2" />Option 2
<br />
<input name="choices" type="checkbox" value="something3" />Option 3
<br />
<input name="choices" type="checkbox" value="something4" />Option 4
<br />
```

Goes with this jQuery:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    //Check boxes
    $("input:checkbox[name=choices]:checked").each(function() {
        console.log("Checkbox: " + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

You can't deselect a radio button unless you want to deselect all of them using either a reset element, which will reset your entire form, or creating a custom function just for radios (that would clear all the choices anyway).

The deselect could be routed to your `name=None` radio button with the following code:

```
$(".rad[name=None]").click(function() {
    $(".rad").removeAttr("checked");
});
```